# QGIS Several overlap / intersect geoprocessing

Tags: qgis, clip

First time asking here, I hope you guys can help me:

So I have this polygon layer with multiple overlapping buffer polygons (these buffers are based on a point layer).

I also have another layer (let's call it "forest") from which I need to extract polygons that are covered by the buffers (using either Clip or Intersection).

My problem is if two buffers overlaps, nor the clip tool or the intersect tool can duplicate the polygons so each buffer has "their own" polygons extracted from "forest".

That might not be clear, so here's a situaton: Let's say that Buffer B1 and Buffer B2 completely overlaps. I need polygons from "Forest" covered by B1 so I can run stats on them, but I would need copies of the same polygons (since B1 and B2 completely overlaps) associated with B2 so I can run the same stats for B2.

I could do it the long way by selecting each buffer individually and clip "Forest", so I would have one layer by buffer, and then merge them all togheter, but I'd like to save time ...

Any clue?

Comment: Perhaps a spatial join http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html is what you're after. I can understand Clip not having overlapping output cliped polygons but Intersect should have overlapping intersected areas B1:Forest B2:Forest complete.

Comment: As a matter of fact you are right. I might have messed up with polygon selection while using Intersection. I tried again after selecting several overlapping polygons and it totally work, Thanks a lot!